# How to create a SQLite Database in Android using the API

Tags: android

I am unable to create a new Database using the API

```
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreate(String path,CursorFactory Factory);
```

When I am using this API, it's throwing an exception

> Unable to open database file

Please help me how to fix this exception.

Comment: provide some code you tried...

Comment: database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(uri.getPath(), null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to create table "Settings" table and "myDB.db". Use this class to create DB and tables

```
public class MyDbConnector extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "MyDbConnector";
    public MyDbConnector(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDB.db", null, 3);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_SETTINGS + " ("
              + Constants.TABLE_SETTINGS_FIELD_KEY + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "
              + Constants.TABLE_SETTINGS_FIELD_VALUE + " TEXT);"
              );
    }
}
```

And to Read/Write in DB use,

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new MyDbConnector(this).getReadableDatabase(); //To read tables in DB
SQLiteDatabase db = new MyDbConnector(this).getWritableDatabase(); // To write something in DB
```

Comment: I want to open the Database without using the SQLiteOpenHelper Class..is it possible to open/create a database without using the OpenHelper Class?

Comment: There are easy way to do same thing, than Why you want to open Database without SQLLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this function: [getWritableDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29)

Comment: But how to use this method for creating a new database??

Comment: @Prachi: Maybe I should have made it clear that you will have to instantiate a SQLiteOpenHelper object first and then you can call that function. Just look at the constructor for that class to see what you need to give it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper